# Filtering HTML document with 1-10k keywords

Tags: c#, regex, full-text-search, string-matching

I have a html Document and want to filter it against the occurrency of multiple (1 - 10k) [1k at the moment, later on up to 10k] keywords.

I have a precompiled regex which stores my searchterms like:

```
static Regex r = new Regex(@"keyword1|keyword2|keyword999",RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is my code:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
MatchCollection matches = Cache.r.Matches(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
string s = "";
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        s += m.Value + ",";
    }
}
long time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Console.Write(time + " = "+matches.Count+" -> "+s );
```

The average time takes about 5-8 seconds. Which is way too much.
Is there any efficient way to filter a html document against alot of keywords?
Or maybe there are more efficient algorythms to filter this..

Comment: What do you need to know about or do with the html? Do you need to know which words occurs, how many times they occurs?

Comment: and what are those keywords..we cant read your mind..

Comment: I want to know if there appear custom keywords. It could be anything. And I want to know which keywords matched

Comment: @unr3al011 You should escape the keywords using `Regex.Escape` before using it as regex else if `.` or `*` occur in keywords,it would be treated as special chars.

Comment: I want it to be treated as special chars

Comment: Since the keywords are fixed string, and there are a lot of keywords, you can check out this article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_finite_set_of_patterns . The Regex class seems that it will not collapse 2 piece of similar text into one, so I think it will perform as bad as naive string searching algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **lboshuizen** pointed out

> Creating a regex with 10k keywords seems not the way to go [...]

If you can afford spawning multiple threads you can scan the document in parallel for occurences of keywords:

```
IEnumerable<string> keywords = LoadKeywords();
List<string> list = new List<string>();
keywords.AsParallel()
    .Aggregate(list, (seed, keyword) =>
    {
        if(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Contains(keyword))
            seed.Add(keyword);
        return seed;
    });
```

Comment: spawning multiple threads seams to be an nice idea but how can I wait until processing is finished? I think my code will continue running but processing of the threads may not have finished or am I wrong?

Comment: @unr3al011, your process will not continue untill the parallel query finishes execution.

Comment: @unr3al011, I do not understand your question. However, all you need to know is that you don't have to worry about joining or waiting threads using the construct in the answer.

Comment: thank you very much! this one is REALLY fast. Average 50ms for checking 900 words. Is there any possibility to make it wildcard ready?

Comment: @unr3al011, I gave you a template of what to do. You can extend your logic as you desire :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `StringBuilder` instead of `string`..

Unless you tell us more about what the keywords are,there is hardly any optimization..

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers are already pretty good, but I figured I'd throw this in as well ...

I've done the same thing and I used the HTML Agility Pack to help cut down on what I was analyzing for keywords.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It's very easy to take an HTML fragment, search only for textual nodes and then run your keyword analysis over that space instead of the entire document.

Also it helps get rid of false positives (keywords appearing in javascript comments, alt tags, whatever else).

Just an idea to try and trim down your search space.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

Creating a regex with 10k keywords seems not the way to go from my POV. A regex is greedy and will try all kind of redundant matches. (=wasting time)

Building regex's with smaller keyword-sets and run them incremental in your html document.

Optimization can be to remove the the matched keywords (and related content) from the document, the will shrink and the remaining regex's has much less to do == run faster.

Or

Turn it around, don;t use a regex to scan agains a document.
Break down the document in to words and check them agains a dictionary. I doubt that the document will contain all 10k words. (looping from the smallest set is more efficient then from the largest set)

Comment: I think there will be no different in how the matching will be carried out (probably equivalent to naive string search algorithm). Doing with small regex is only useful for memory.

Comment: Not completely true. Letting regex do a "brute force" matching can be worse then checking against a dict. It involves a bit more thinking, but thats the essence of my work

Comment: I am referring to the "Building regex's with smaller keyword-sets and run them incremental in your html document." approach. For the other approach (check against dictionary), it is quite dependent on the implementation (hashing or tree like structure that emulating a DFA seems to be more efficient).